# How to show dialog onsuccess of saving data to database?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have created a wepapp using Facelets, JSF 2.0 and PrimeFaces for storing employee data and it is successfully storing the data to database.

However, I want want to add a handler to `onsuccess` of storing to show a dialog with Ok button and after clicking Ok button the page should be reloaded. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: just 2c... don't you think it's easier to add a message to JSF context saying that the insert was sucessful or an error message to JSF context if you catch some exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try this :

```
<[..] onsuccess="PF('dialog').show();" />

<p:dialog widgetVar="dialog" [..]>
   ...
    <p:commandButton value="OK" action="#{yourBean.yourAction}" />
</p:dialog>
```

Comment: Thanks... :) It is working...IN ACTION AM CALLING A METHOD WITH PAGE NAME AS ARGUMENT WHICH RELOADS OR REFRESH THE CURRENT INSTANCE PAGE